# Optional regex match for a group doesn't work

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I have the following sentence

```
#bb John can #20 jiang stone [voila]
```

I want my C# regex to give me 5 matches to my groups

```
#bb
John Can
20
jiang stone
voila
```

Of which the tokens in #bb and voila positions are optional.

I used the following regex expression which works nicely in a sentence that doesn't have the first #bb - for e.g.

```
John can #20 jiang stone [voila]
```

gives me 4 correct tokens with the expression

```
@"(.*)#(\d+)(.*\s)(?:\[(.*)\])?"
```

Yet when I extend this with

```
@"(?:#[a-zA-Z])?(.*)#(\d+)(.*\s)(?:\[(.*)\])?"
```

It doesn't work. The #bb in the beginning of the sentence isn't matched as a separate token - instead I get a match as

```
b John Can
```

I've tried several variations but none give me an optional match to the first #.. match. What I want is that this can be #{1 or 2 characters} and this can be optional. I can have it, or it might be missing, in which case the rest should return the tokens.

What's wrong with my regex?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
#[a-zA-Z]
```

means a `#` followed by a *single* ASCII letter. You want this:

```
#[a-zA-Z]{1,2}
```

in order to allow one *or two* ASCII letters.

In addition, this:

```
(?:...)
```

means a *non*-capturing group. If you want a token to show up in your results, you need to wrap it in *capturing* parentheses:

```
(...)
```

So, putting it together:

```
@"((?:#[a-zA-Z]{1,2})?)(.*)#(\d+)(.*\s)(?:\[(.*)\])?"
```

(Note: it's not obvious to me how you want the whitespace to be handled; you may need to tweak the above a bit for your needs. Note, in particular, that if there's whitespace between the first two tokens, the above pattern will treat it as being part of the second token.)

Comment: Perfect! You appear to be a god among regexers, good sir. Am learning it, struggling on the way.

Comment: I seem have to reacted too quickly -- need a bit more help. When I use more than 1 word in the last section - i.e. instead of [voila] if I say [voila there] then the last token breaks...any idea what I should do to capture the full sentence?

Comment: @jeremy: One possibility to try is changing `(.*\s)` to `(.*?\s)`. The `*?` notation is like the `*` notation, but whereas the `*` notation is "greedy" -- it wants to match as much as it can, and it only backtracks if it has to -- the `*?` notation is "reluctant" -- it wants to match as *little* as it can. Alternatively, if you know that the "jiang stone" token will never contain `[`, you can change `(.*\s)` to `([^\[]*\s)` so that it never swallows `[`.

Comment: Yep, that solves it (I used ([^\[]*\s)! Thanks much. Of course I need to now sit and learn how it works etc.